# How to create such buttons with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, button

I'm very new to WordPress (tbh, it's my first time working with it). And I need to make a website as my school project using CMS. Creating pages with templates is alright, but I have a lot of troubles with buttons. I found this website, and I can see it using WordPress. I need such buttons as on this page https://movie-chooser.co.ua/random-movie-2/ (they appear when you hover over the image). Is this a default option for buttons in WordPress? If not, is there a plugin for this or what is the way to add them on my images?

Answer (score 0):

First Install Elementor plugin **https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/**
and go to page when you add button and open page with elementor
and do drag and drop any element like button, space, text editor etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to achieve that:

1. Overwritting Wordpress CSS
2. Using a plugin
3. Create your own shortcode

**1 - Overwriting Wordpress CSS**

If you manage to display all the elements using wordpress template, and your only issue is to display buttons over the images, then it should only be a matter of CSS

**2 - Using a plugin**

The idea here is to find a plugin that help you to create/display the informations you need (maybe you'll need to add functionnality to basic post though custom fields or  using a [custom post type](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/)).

Once you find the right plugin, again if the plugin dosen't directly offert some settings on the design then you'll have to overwrite the plugin's CSS rules to display the elements as you want.

**3 - Create your own shortcode**

If you're new to Wordpress I wouldn't recommend this method as it is kind of advanced, unless you're comfortable with PHP/HTML/CSS (optionaly JS).
This is the more flexible solution as you can basically control anything, but it will require you to understand some core concepts of Wordpress like [WP Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and how [custom queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) works.

The idea here is to create a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).
THis shortcode refere to a custom made PHP function, in which you can create a custom request to fetch the informations you need to display from Wordpress database, and display it in an HTML structure that you decide.
THen angain, you'll just have to customize it though CSS.

Note : no need to create a whole plugin if you decide to create a shortcode, you can use the template functions.php file for that.